# QML engine doesn't import C++ model correctly

Tags: c++, qt, qml

**Overview**

I'm working on a project to learn how to implement C++ models in a QML project and I've ran into an issue that I can't quite figure out. I believe I've implemented the model correctly since I can manipulate it on the C++ side without issue, but I'm doing something wrong trying to expose it to the QML engine.

What I'm trying to do:

- Create the model in `main.cpp`
- Fill it with some data
- Call `setContextProperty()` with the model on the engine's root context
- In `main.qml` set up a `GridView` component using the C++ model

After doing the above, the project runs but nothing is displayed in the window. Then I tried to run `main.qml` using Qt Creator's tool QML Utility tool. Again, it runs but nothing is displayed. In the General Messages tab I get the message:

```
Starting external tool "/path/to/Qt/6.3.1/gcc_64/bin/qml /path/to/project/main.qml"
file:///path/to/project/main.qml:23: ReferenceError: cellModel is not defined
```

**Some Context For The Curious**

The project is to implement Conway's Game of Life as a simple proof of concept to prepare for a more complex future project. Behind the scenes, the C++ model `CellModel` uses class `Environment` which manages a 2D list of pointers to instances of class `Cell` which handle updating at timed intervals and holding the state values respectively.

**Relevant Code**

`main.cpp`

```cpp
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>

#include "cellmodel.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#if QT_VERSION < QT_VERSION_CHECK(6, 0, 0)
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
#endif
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    CellModel model = CellModel(nullptr);

    model.resize(40, 40);
    model.fillWithSoup();

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    QQmlContext* context = engine.rootContext();
    context->setContextProperty("cellModel", &model);

    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

`cellmodel.h`

```cpp
#include <QAbstractItemModel>
#include <QDir>
#include <QHash>
#include <QByteArray>

class Environment;
class EnvironmentBuilder;

class CellModel : public QAbstractItemModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

    enum Roles {
        Living = Qt::UserRole + 1
    };
    Q_ENUM(Roles)

    explicit CellModel(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    Environment* environment() const {return m_environment;}
    void setEnvironmefnt(Environment* environment);

    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const override;
    bool setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value,
                 int role = Qt::EditRole) override;
    QModelIndex index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex& parent = QModelIndex()) const override;
    QModelIndex parent(const QModelIndex& index) const override;
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const override;
    Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex &index) const override;

signals:
    void stateUpdated();

public slots:
    Q_INVOKABLE void load(QString filename = "save.gol");
    Q_INVOKABLE void save(QString filename = "save.gol");
    Q_INVOKABLE void setSaveDirectory(QString directory = QDir::current().path());

    Q_INVOKABLE void clearAll();
    Q_INVOKABLE void fillWithSoup(qreal density = 0.4);

    Q_INVOKABLE void nextStep();

    Q_INVOKABLE void resize(int height = 1, int width = 1);

private:
    EnvironmentBuilder* m_builder;
    Environment* m_environment;
};
```

`main.qml`

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

Window {
    id: window
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    GridView {
        property real cellScale: 10

        implicitHeight: 400
        implicitWidth: 400

        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter

        cellHeight: cellScale
        cellWidth: cellScale

        model: cellModel

        delegate: Rectangle {
            border.width: 1
            border.color: "black"
            color: model.living ? "#cacaca" : "#424242"
        }
    }
}
```

**What I've Tried**

To check whether I made some error in subclassing `QAbstractItemModel`, I made a simpler model inheriting `QAbstractListModel` and tried using it instead only to face the same results. So the issue must lie in how I've tried exposing the model to the QML engine, but the `setContextProperty()` function seems so straightforward I fail to see how I could be misusing it.

Comment: I think you might want to use TableView, since GridView is supposed to show a 1-dimensional list as items in a grid. Not sure if GridView bails out if the columnCount is higher than 1, but one issue at a time ;-)

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that I misunderstood my issue! As @Amfasis pointed out, a `TableView` component would be more appropriate for my application. I changed the `GridView` component accordingly and everything works. I was exposing the model to QML correctly the whole time.

Also of note: In my question text I mentioned that I ran `main.qml` in the QML Utility tool and got a ReferenceError. However, I've realized that the QML Utility tool would always read the file without my model being in the QML context since I exposed it in `main.cpp` which the tool doesn't read.